# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: vb.net

So I'm trying to read a data row (of school subjects) from a MS Access file and add new `ToolStripMenuItems` during runtime named according to the data row items. This is my code:

```
    dataFile = "C:\Users\Abenati Mawisa\Documents\Database1.mdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source =" & dataFile

    myConnection.Open()
    Dim str As String = "SELECT * FROM Gr8Subjects WHERE ID_PassportNum = ?"
    Dim subjects(8) As String
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID_PassportNum", myuserName)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader 'The error in the title is generated here

    While dr.Read()
        For k = 0 To 8
            subjects(k) = dr("Subject" & k + 1).ToString
        Next
    End While

    myConnection.Close()

    SubjectsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Clear()
    For l = 0 To 8
        SubjectsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(subjects(l))
    Next
```

myuserName is declared publicly and come from a different form. The code has run before without the error.
Before this part of my code,

```
    Dim str As String = "SELECT * FROM Gr8Subjects WHERE ID_PassportNum = ?"
    Dim subjects(8) As String
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID_PassportNum", myuserName)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

looked like this,

```
    Dim str As String = "SELECT * FROM Gr8Subjects WHERE (ID_PassportNum = '" & myuserName & "')"
    Dim subjects(8) As String
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

I changed it after a bit of research, but it still doesn't work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Make sure `myuserName` is not empty

Comment: If `myuserName` was `Nothing` then that last code snippet would try to match the `ID_PassportNum` column to an empty string.  The second code snippet would not.  The second code snippet would actually require `myuserName` to be an empty `String` for that to happen. If it was `Nothing` then you'd get that error message, because a parameter `Value` must either be a valid value or be `DBNull.Value` to represent null.